# Only route a specific IP address through VPN

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04, gateway

I am on a ubuntu 18.04 machine and want to route only a single IP through the VPN-Tunnel to my workplace network, namely the network file share.

I have been given a .ovpn client configuration file with the whole authentication stuff inside and have been able to set it up and access the file server. To do so, I went the GUI route: [Ubuntu system settings > Network > VPN > Import from file...]. However, once I've activated the VPN, I can't access the internet anymore: trying to open google.com results in a timeout.

I've added the following to the bottom of my .ovpn file:

```
route-nopull
route <file server ip> 255.255.255.255
```

But when I try to use the [Import from file...] again, the GUI stops me and says I have to enter a gateway address for this specific route before I can save this VPN-configuration. The `255.255.255.255` from the `route` directive above is filled in as the netmask.

I have no idea what gateway ip I have to enter there. I have tried:

- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.42<sup>1</sup>.1

<sup>1</sup> Not actually 42, but some specific number pulled from `ipconfig` output on a windows machine inside the network.

How do I find the correct gateway ip? Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Do `ip route`, look at `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1` (they are used instead of the default route by OpenVPN so the default route can be kept), write down the "via", "delete those and replace with a route for your single IP address to the address you've written down. Once this works, you can think about automating it (OpenVPN has hooks for it, but I'd have to look this up).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following options:

```
route-noexec
up misc/up.sh
```

Where `misc/up.sh` refers to a script relative to the config file. ( My config is in `/etc/openvpn/foo.conf` and the script is in `/etc/openvpn/misc/up.sh`) This script would then contain the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

ip route add <file_server_ip> via $4
#ip route add <file_server_ip> dev $1
```

This lets the VPN server configure your endpoint IP address, but routing will be handled by the script. If the above doesn't work, try using just the second line.

Answer (score 0):

route gateway is practically arbitrary at least for a tun setup, as it's not necessary /  actually useful (the actual gateway, when it's not the server, is determined by `iroute` instead).

My guess is either you are filtering the `route-gateway` option in the client conf, or the server conf simply isn't pushing it (not using the `server` directive).

The address "should be" the VPN IP of the server, but it shouldn't matter even if you just use any IP (though I am not sure if the "smart" GUI would check it against anything; it shouldn't be able to unless you are doing a one-to-one setup with `ifconfig`).

P.S. In other words, if the connection doesn't work after you fill in some random IP for the field, it may not be the cause of you problem.